# Do webm <video> elements support time scrubbing?

Tags: html5-video

I am attempting to use an HTML5 video player to preview a local video before uploading it. The video is stored as a webm blob, which I convert into a data URL so that it can be sent as a JSON payload around a Chrome Extension.

The video plays great, but I can't seem to scrub the time at all. The time increments, but trying to use the controls just does nothing. The control circle is completely to the left of the control bar, and doesn't increment as the video progresses. I do not see the total time either.

Once the video completes, the control bar works as expected. The total time is present, and the video can be scrubbed. Playing it at this point causes the control circle to proceed from left->right as expected.

The weird part is that I can set currentTime on the video before it finishes and it works great.

Here's my  construction. There's nothing fancy here:

```
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    video.controls = true
    video.preload = 'auto'
    video.currentTime = 30 // This works, somehow
    video.id = 'video'
    video.width = 800

    const source = document.createElement('source')
    source.type = 'video/webm'
    source.src = resp.recordingDataUrl // This looks like data:video/webm;base64,GkXfo59Ch.....

    video.appendChild(source)
    document.getElementById('root').appendChild(video)
```

Am I missing something necessary to scrub the time? I have noticed this when browsing videos on the web (usually Reddit), which makes me wonder if there's a webm bug of some sort.

Comment: An alternative question is: is there a way to preview a video locally (no server upload) without using a data URL? A downside of the current approach is that it ends up killing the page's HTML due to the size of the video string.